# Search form with edit_resource_path as action in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a resource Invoice and every invoice has an edit path:

http://localhost:3000/invoices/1/edit

On my index page where I will all my invoices I want to have an input field and a submit button to jump right to the edit page for a certain invoice:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="???" method="get">
       <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Invoice ID" name="id" >
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Show</button>
</form>
```

How do I have to define the action so that if I enter for example 1 and click on Show it goes right to my edit method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this in your html

```
<%= form_tag find_invoice_url do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :invoice_number =>
    <%= f.submit "Search" =>
<= end =>
```

then you would need to add a route

```
  post '/invoices/find_invoice', to: "invoices#find_invoice",
  as: "find_invoice"
```

then in your controller something like

```
def find_invoice
  invoice = Invoice.find_by_id(params[:invoice_number])
  if invoice
    redirect_to invoice_url(invoice.id) #whatever your edit route is
  else
    redirect_to root_url #anywhere really
  end
end
```

Comment: may want this to be a "get" if users expect to be browse through invoices they have edited previously - depends on usage

Answer (score 0):

if you are iterating through all the invoices, you wouldn't need an input field.
assuming that you have an invoice obhect, you would just do something like

```
<%= form_tag edit_invoice_path(invoice), method: "get" do -%>
  <%= submit_tag "Show", class="btn btn-info" %>
<% end %>
```

You may want the button to say edit instead - that's more of a ux "principle of least surprise" issue

Comment: Thanks, all my invoices have an edit button already. But I want to add this form at the top of the index page so that the user can go directly to the edit page if he knows the id.

Comment: Okay - you want an input field at the top of the form.  I would create a new action on the invoice controller "edit_any" or something like that.  Then in the controller action, you can pick up the submitted id and redirect to the edit page passing the id to it